# Flutter buttons that create widgets or similar

Tags: flutter, button, widget

I am very new with flutter and coding in general, I'm studying and learning the foundation of coding.
Starting from the classic template app of a new flutter project, the "+" button in the bottom right corner add 1 to the count in the center of the screen.
I would like to know how can that button create a widget where I can write a note and store it in my app?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [simple app](https://i.imgur.com/Pn61uFT.gif) which works like the default counter example. In this app clicking the floating action button creates a dialogue box where the user can enter a note. On clicking 'save note', the note will be added to a notes list and the new list of notes can be seen on the screen.

Let me also add that this way of manipulating state(list of notes in this case) is not recommended. Since this is just an example, I guess it's alright.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  String _note = '';
  final List<String> _notes = ['Default first note'];

  _showAlertDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _notes.add(_note);
                      controller.clear();
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Save Note'))
            ],
            title: const Text('Enter Note'),
            content: TextField(
              controller: controller,
              decoration:
                  const InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _note = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  _resetNotes() {
    setState(() {
      _notes
          .retainWhere((element) => element.toString() == 'Default first note');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _notes.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Text(index.toString()),
              title: Text(_notes[index].toString()),
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _showAlertDialog,
            tooltip: 'AddNote',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _resetNotes,
            tooltip: 'Reset',
            child: const Icon(Icons.replay),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```